# Org Mode link to structure blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Is there a way of linking to a specific structure block in org mode?

I have a block of text as follows:

```
* Heading

Some text

** Subheading

some text

#+BEGIN_PROSE Lorem
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
#+END_PROSE

some text
```

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-l</kbd> would only store a link to the top of `subheading`.

I would like to be able the use `[[Lorem]]` to jump to the bock of text.

Would that be possible?

－－－－－

## Update:

Because the text would be printed, I would like any dedicated target to stay within the template code or comment.

I've tried `#+BEGIN_PROSE <<Lorem>>` and `# <<Lorem>>` but neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put a name on the block like this:

```
* Heading

Some text

** Subheading

some text

#+name: Lorem
#+BEGIN_PROSE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
#+END_PROSE

some text

* Heading with link to Lorem

Here is the link:  [[Lorem]].
```

Answer (score 1):

Just insert a [dedicated target](https://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html) `<<lorem>>` at the place where you would like to jump to with `[[lorem]]`.

It's clear that John Kitchin's solution works with blocks.
What I meant is:

```
* Heading

Some text [[lorem]]

** Subheading

some text

#+BEGIN_PROSE Lorem
<<lorem>> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
#+END_PROSE

some text
```

Comment: I tried `#+BEGIN_PROSE <<Lorem>>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Because the text would be published, I would like the dedicated target to stay within the comment.

Comment: Would it be trivial to tweak the behavior of structure templates to allow this function?

Comment: @Sati: I edited my answer to address your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of this function. I did not use it because that would add `<<lorem>>` to the printed text. We could consider `<<Lorem>> ipsum`, though, but that would only work if the title/name of the block can be found within the text itself, as in this situation.